# .yaml file for Google Kubernetes engine static website?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to set up a static website .yaml file for a Google Kubernetes Engine but it keeps giving me errors. I can't find a single example of doing this on Google or on StackOverflow.

Here's what i have so far...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
Namespace: default
name: "rcts_test"
app: rcts
protocol: TCP
```

I'm getting an error...

```
error when retrieving current configuration of: [yaml_file_contents] from server for: "app.yaml" resource name may not be empty
```

On a side note, it's really annoying that I can't cut-and-paste to or from the Google Cloud Shell Terminal.

Comment: what's failing in static site ? deployment or not able to create the service ?

Comment: Check whether you provided a **name** under the **metadata** section. Can you add a **deployment** manifest to your question? Which part is failing, is it deploying the application or creating a service?

Comment: Using Kubernetes was overkill guys. I'm just going to use Google App Engine instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error might come when the **manifest file syntax** is not correct. Like missing the **metadata**, **name** etc. You can try using the following manifest for your service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rcts-test
spec:
  selector:
    app: rcts #Modify as your deployment label
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deploy-app-cluster#deploy_an_application_to_the_cluster) for detailed information about deploying an application in GKE.

Comment: HI @Myuser03 did you get a chance to look into this answer? is it helpful?

Comment: Yes. Very helpful thanks @Dharani Dhar Golladasari. Turns out though, there's a much simpler way of doing this. I should have been using Google App Engine instead for a simple ChatGPT implementation. D'oh.